# Division PHP in foreach

Tags: php

I have

```
$div = 100
$value = 502

$sum = $val / $div
```

how can i get output like this

```
100
100
100
100
100
2
```

any reffrence to learn more?

Comment: `$value` is a single integer so `foreach($value as $val){` makes no sense really

Comment: how to looping for output like that?

Comment: how do you derive the expected results? What operations do you need to do to `$value` first?

Comment: Do you mean 1000 instead of 100? Or maybe 10 instead of 100?

Comment: That result doesn't really match the input data? How could 5200 be represented represent as 100 x 5 + 2 (which adds up to 502)?

Comment: @gaganshera 100

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry that means $value = 502

Comment: That changes everything. Please always proof read your question before posting it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry for that

Comment: If you need that exact output, why not print that? Or is there any rule behind this example, such that these numbers could be dynamic? If yes, can you explain that rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$div = 100;
$value = 502;

while($value > $div) {
    $value = $value - $div;
    echo $div . "<br>";
}
echo $value
```

Comment: u got it man, i need learn more